# Help understand UART diagram

Tags: uart, modeling

I'm writing a university paper about UART as part of my computer science education. I'm looking at different state diagrams of UART, somewhat puzzled that they are so different. I already asked some questions about it and I begun to understand the basics. My plan is to make a good state diagram about the UART I own: The avalon_altera_uart which is part of FPGA:s from Altera (I own the FPGA Altera DE2-115). That particular UART is desribed in page 68 of the manual. But there is no state diagram for that so I must learn how to make a state diagram for that and then I can model it in NuSMV and step through the states.

My question is about a detailed diagram I see on page 35 of this slideshow https://www.slideshare.net/AkshayShah57/usbbasedclosedloopdigitalcontrolsystem

I don't understand what all his variables are. Is the UART 16 bits? Does RxD mean received 16 bits? What does rsr mean? What does dcnt mean? What does b mean? Can I use the understanding of his UART diagram to make a state diagram of my UART (https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_embedded_ip.pdf#page=68) ?

I just begun to make some code in NuSMV to model it, the code is not right and some of it is "dummy code" but I use it to develop the model in NuSMV that should correspond to a state diagram of the altera_avalon_uart.

```
MODULE main
-- ACTIVITIES
-- 1. Fill in the smv definitions
-- 2. Then run this file
VAR
-- system outputs
    Bit1 : boolean; -- Boolean variable
    Bit2 : boolean;
    state : {s1, s2, s3, s4}; -- scalar variable
    -- the model has states: location, that equals to idle, start, top, data, paritybit and tsr
    location : {idle, start, stop, data, paritybit, tsr};
    load : 0 .. 1;
IVAR
-- system inputs
    input : boolean;

ASSIGN
    init (location) := idle;
    init (state) := s1;
    init (Bit1) := FALSE;
    init (Bit2) := FALSE;
    next (location) :=
        case
            (location = idle) & (load = 1) : start; -- if state is idle and load=1 then next state is start
            (location = start) : data; --if state is start then next state is data  
            TRUE : location; -- if conditions fail, then do not change location
        esac;
    next (load) :=
        case
            (location = start) & load < 1 : load + 1;
            TRUE : load; -- otherwise, do not do anything to load
        esac;
    next (state) :=
        case
            state = s1 & input = TRUE : s2;
            state = s2 & input = FALSE : s3;
            state = s2 & input = TRUE : s4;
            state = s3 & input = FALSE : s1;
            state = s3 & input = TRUE : s2;
            state = s4 & input = FALSE : s3;
            TRUE : state; -- why?
        esac;
    next (Bit1) :=
        case
        -- To Do 
            Bit1 = FALSE : Bit2;
            TRUE : Bit2;
        esac;
    next (Bit2) :=
        case
        -- To Do 
            Bit2 = FALSE : Bit2;
            TRUE : Bit2;
        esac;
```

I have done the following diagram of UART that I think is not right, since it models the bits and the bits are not exactly the states.

[image]

Comment: *since it models the bits and the bits are not exactly the states.* - it models the states, some of which happen to be named after bits.

Comment: A FIFO is a useful addition to a UART, but is not part of a basic UART.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all probability:

- Rxd is the state of the received serial data pin.
- rsr is the receive shift register.
- dcnt is probably a bit count.
- b looks like the state of the Rxd pin sampled at the center of a bit time, but not having the HDL available that is a guess.

16 bits is I suppose possible in a uart, but I have never seen one, usually the things are around 8 bits (Sometimes 9, occasionally 5/6/7).

No idea about that NuSMV thing, but it produces ugly looking state diagrams.